# Using my Home server Mail server and pointing DNS

Tags: dns, server, webserver, mail

I have my own webserver on my home PC. I also have a mail server too. I have been pointing my paid server to my mail server and I'm just wasting $15 a month for this, so how can I get my domain to point to my server without the paid webhost?

Comment: How are you currently "pointing" your paid "mail" server to your home server? As you suggest, this is a "DNS" thing, so you don't necessarily need a "webhost". You need a domain registrar that provides a DNS service.